# How to set framework search path to root project Framework search path?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, ios-frameworks

[image]

I have created one multitarget framework `SwiftyGmail` which is dependent on `AFNetworking` and `AFNetworking` is added using pod.

Now I want this framework development side by side with main project `FrameworkTest` So I have added `SwiftyGmail`as child project and also added `AFNetworking` using pod. Now problem is `SwiftyGmail` is not able to locate the `AFNetworking` header.

How do I set the Framework search path of `SwiftyGmail` so that it can find the `AFNetworking` from root project(`FrameworkTest`).

Comment: Have you tried $(SRCROOT)

Comment: $(SRCROOT)  gives `SwiftyGmail`.